# what type of parameter accepts both List and DataRowCollection and is both indexable and numberable?

Tags: c#, collections

I want to write a method that has parameter that accepts both `List<T>` and `DataRowCollection` as value and is both indexable and numberable but I don't know how to do it. Is it possible with available classes and interfaces?

Thanks & BR - matti

Comment: By `List` do you mean `List<T>`?

Comment: Have a look into `Object`, It's THE one-size-fits-all parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx

Comment: @richard: yes List<T>. @Bazz: true, but not beautiful solution

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify a type constraint like `where T : []` and there is no generic interface for an indexer property. `List` and `DataRowCollection` both are `IEnumerable` and `ICollection` but I assume that doesn't gain you much. So no, it's not possible to specify something like "A type needs to be an indexable collection".

**Update**: I just saw that `DataRowCollection` has a `List` property which returns the collection as a `ArrayList` which is an `IList`. So assuming you want to write an extension method you could target it to `IList`

**Update 2**: Another option: you could target `IEnumerable` and use Linq `ElementAt()`. Not sure if it will use the index property for `DataRowCollection` though.

Comment: except that it's not working I getError 10 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'

Comment: @matti: Use extension method `Enumerable.Cast<T>` to convert `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 0):

Both [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and [`DataRowCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.aspx) implement [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) and [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx) so you could use either depending what the method needs to do.

Comment: @digEmAll: there is no `IIndexable` interface in the BCL. Neither of the two common interfaces have an `Item` property to give indexed access. Could use `Enumerable.ElementAt` to do this (in O(n) time if there is no `IList<T>` implementation). In the end overloads might be needed, but the question is too vague to help further.